# Commerce product order/sort options

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugins

What are all the available options that products can be ordered by?

`craft.commerce.products({ order: '???' })`

I have found this reference https://craftcommerce.com/docs/products-fields#templating but it does not list the available options.

Bonus points if it includes the key that sorts by sales (aka popularity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `craft.commerce.products` you're asking Craft for an [Commerce_ProductModel](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/product-model).

So you could sort by:

- title (alpha)
- defaultPrice
- type
- promotable (sale products on top)
- postDate (newest products)
- .. etc.

To sort by sales (popularity), you might consider something like BonFire's [Popular Products](http://www.hellobonfire.com/product/popular-products-plugin-for-craft) plugin which keeps track of how many purchases were made and how many times the product was viewed, very similar to Ben Croker's [EntryCount](https://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-entry-count) plugin.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!